# What spellchecker does StackOverflow use?

Tags: spell-checking, wmd

I'm sold on the WMD textarea and markdown, but I'd like to give the same features to my users too!

Comment: Only dumb, out of date browsers that don't support things like Canvas don't have spell-checkers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None. Whatever spell checker you are seeing is built into your browser.

Comment: actually firefox has it too, and I'm pretty sure so does Opera.

Comment: Yes, opera has it too, but you need to the GNU Aspell (unless you're in MAC): http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/spellcheck/